# PHP print percentage monthly user login

Tags: php, mysql

I count monthly user login with this function :

```
    $DB_QUERY = DataAccess::fetch("SELECT COUNT(user) AS TOTAL FROM " . ACCESSLOGS . " WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(loggedin)) = MONTH(curdate())
 AND user = ? AND success = 1 LIMIT 1", $_SESSION['name']);
```

result is : `12`

Now, how do can i show with percentage in month?! like : `30%`

Comment: You probably need a sub-query which will give you the total number of users.

Comment: `(12 / daysInMonth) * 100`? Percentage of what exactly?

Comment: divide by 31 should do it, unless you need accuracy of exact number of days in a month. if you require more accuracy, you'll need to use a calendar table to derive this info

Comment: You might want to `COUNT(DISTINCT user)` in case someone decides to login more than once in a month.

Comment: @MarkBaker: Each user login at least once a day.

Comment: @amdixon - MySQL does actually have a [LAST_DAY()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) function to give the number of days in a month

Comment: @MarkBaker agreed - dont technically need a calendar table for this purpose ( although its useful in general for business logic with dates.. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$day = 12
$day / date('t') *100 ;
```

`date('t')` will return day of current month.

Check **[PHP date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)** function